# Champernowne constant - summation and behavior of terms in continued fraction expansion

Tags: continued-fractions, constants

Is there an infinite summation that gives the Champernowne constant? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) has one, and so does [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChampernowneConstant.html). Are they valid? If so, could someone explain why, i.e how do they work?

Also, why are some of the terms in its continued function expansion extremely large compared to the neighboring terms?

Comment: The Champernowne constant has some very good rational approximations --- this is how one proves it's transcendental. Good rational approximations correspond to large partial quotients.